# Colorbar's colormap not updating when also adding a label to the bar

Tags: matlab, drawing, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

Below's some code that generates a figure that has a colorbar with a custom label:

```
function q41269479
% Create an axes:
figure();
% Display an image:
hIm = imagesc(peaks);
% Adjust colormap and colorbar:
h = colorbar; colormap(gray);
ylabel(h, '\Delta', 'Rotation', 0, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.48 1.05]);
```

What I **expect to get**:
[image: Expected result]

What I **actually get**:
[image]

Notice that the `colorbar` is still `parula` (the default) and not `gray` as I asked it politely to be.

The natural way to solve some graphical glitch like this is by "invalidating" the figure... Unfortunately, the popular commands `drawnow` and `refresh`, executed after the figure is at the shown state, do not remedy this situation.

It should be noted that exporting the figure results in the correct colors.

**Question:** Does anybody have an idea why this happens and how to fix it (preferably without workarounds / hacks)?

I'm running R2016b, on Win 7. As far as I know, this does not happen on Octave 4.0.3.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the R2017a prerelease.

Comment: @excaza Well then I suppose they unfixed it since then, seeing how I can replicate this problem in R2018a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several workarounds seem to solve this issue:

```
% Solution 1: adding a pause/drawnow AFTER setting the colormap.
h = colorbar; colormap(gray); pause(eps);
% OR:
h = colorbar; colormap(gray); drawnow;

% Solution 2: change the figure size (e.g. maximize then minimize)
drawnow % Required to avoid Java errors
jFig = get(handle(gcf), 'JavaFrame'); 
jFig.setMaximized(true); pause(0.0001); jFig.setMaximized(false);

% Solution 3: add/remove datatip
hDataCursorMgr = datacursormode(gcf);
hDatatip = createDatatip(hDataCursorMgr,hIm); delete(hDatatip);
```

I have no idea why this happens though. My best guess is that JIT tries to execute these commands on multiple threads. Then, when `colormap` tries to change the colors of the `colorbar`, it encounters an object "locked" by `ylabel`, and as a result cannot perform its function. However the update "directive" *does* make its way into some event queue that execute when certain things happen to the figure.